# DB bulk validation and upload

Tags: database, postgresql, data-warehouse, bulkloader

I am designing an application which will involve bulk upload of records to a Postgres DB (Lets call the schema DB-1). The uploads will be done almost every week. Size could range from a few million to a billion records. The data that is going to be uploaded needs to be validated/cleansed first as it will need to conform to the constaints and format of DB-1. I am thinking of adopting a following approach:

1. Everytime a new upload needs to be done, a new schema is created (Lets call it DB-2 - A staging place) same as DB-1 **but with lenient constraints**. This will make sure that the data gets loaded in the DB-2 to start with.
2. Run a validation process on the data. Initially I was thinking a middleware process but when i realized the amount of data that will be processed, I kind of started thinking about coding a validation+cleansing layer in the DB itself - A set of stored Procs which will run on DB-2, check the data and generate a report with the records which do not conform to the rules (ie constaints present in DB-1, data format etc).
3. After this, the data which needs to be changed again at the source, Step 1 repeated and if all looks ok, then a SELECT INTO DB-1 from DB-2 would shift the valid data to the final desitnation.

What is your opinion on the above process? Any obvious/hidden issues you see here? Suggestions to make it better most welcome.

Thanks

J

Comment: The biggest issue you'll have doing the validation/cleansing part in the DB is that unfortunately any given PostgreSQL backend (connection, session) can use only one CPU. You can get plenty of parallelism using multiple connections, but it's hard to do huge heavy duty work in stored procs without hacks like PL/Proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What other alternatives you think  are feasbile? Read data in a Java code and validate/cleanse it leveraging multiprocessing..?